# What's a good detailed explanation of Tokio's simple TCP echo server example (on GitHub and API reference)?

Tags: rust, async-await, rust-tokio

Tokio has the same example of a simple TCP echo server on its:

- GitHub main page (https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio)
- API reference main page (https://docs.rs/tokio/0.2.18/tokio/)

However, in both pages, there is no explanation of what's actually going on. Here's the example, slightly modified so that the main function does not return `Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>>`:

```rust
use tokio::net::TcpListener;
use tokio::prelude::*;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    if let Ok(mut tcp_listener) = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:8080").await {
        while let Ok((mut tcp_stream, _socket_addr)) = tcp_listener.accept().await {
            tokio::spawn(async move {
                let mut buf = [0; 1024];
                // In a loop, read data from the socket and write the data back.
                loop {
                    let n = match tcp_stream.read(&mut buf).await {
                        // socket closed
                        Ok(n) if n == 0 => return,
                        Ok(n) => n,
                        Err(e) => {
                            eprintln!("failed to read from socket; err = {:?}", e);
                            return;
                        }
                    };
                    // Write the data back
                    if let Err(e) = tcp_stream.write_all(&buf[0..n]).await {
                        eprintln!("failed to write to socket; err = {:?}", e);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

After reading the Tokio documentation (https://tokio.rs/docs/overview/), here's my mental model of this example. A task is spawned for each new TCP connection. And a task is ended whenever a read/write error occurs, or when the client ends the connection (i.e. `n == 0` case). Therefore, if there are 20 connected clients at a point in time, there would be 20 spawned tasks. However, under the hood, this is NOT equivalent to spawning 20 threads to handle the connected clients concurrently. As far as I understand, this is basically the problem that asynchronous runtimes are trying to solve. Correct so far?

Next, my mental model is that a tokio scheduler (e.g. the multi-threaded `threaded_scheduler` which is the default for apps, or the single-threaded `basic_scheduler` which is the default for tests) will schedule these tasks concurrently on 1-to-N threads. (Side question: for the `threaded_scheduler`, is N fixed during the app's lifetime? If so, is it equal to `num_cpus::get()`?). If one task is `.await`ing for the `read` or `write_all` operations, then the scheduler can use **the same thread** to perform more work for one of the other 19 tasks. Still correct?

Finally, I'm curious whether the outer code (i.e. the code that is `.await`ing for `tcp_listener.accept()`) is itself a task? Such that in the 20 connected clients example, there aren't really 20 tasks but 21: one to listen for new connections + one per connection. All of these 21 tasks could be scheduled concurrently on one or many threads, depending on the scheduler. In the following example, I wrap the outer code in a `tokio::spawn` and `.await` the handle. Is it completely equivalent to the example above?

```rust
use tokio::net::TcpListener;
use tokio::prelude::*;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let main_task_handle = tokio::spawn(async move {
        if let Ok(mut tcp_listener) = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:8080").await {
            while let Ok((mut tcp_stream, _socket_addr)) = tcp_listener.accept().await {
                tokio::spawn(async move {
                    // ... same as above ...
                });
            }
        }
    });
    main_task_handle.await.unwrap();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**This answer is a summary of an answer I received on Tokio's Discord from Alice Ryhl. Big thank you!**

First of all, indeed, for the multi-threaded scheduler, the number of OS threads is fixed to `num_cpus`.

Second, Tokio can swap the currently running task at every `.await` on a per-thread basis.

Third, the main function runs in its own task, which is spawned by the `#[tokio::main]` macro.

Therefore, for the first code block example, if there are 20 connected clients, there would be 21 tasks: one for the main macro + one for each of the 20 open TCP streams. For the second code block example, there would be 22 tasks because of the extra outer `tokio::spawn` but it's needless and doesn't add any concurrency.

Comment: Please, correct me if Im wrong. You say that the tasks count is bounded by `num_cpu * thread_per_cpu` ? So, on 4-core machine where 1 thread per core, we are able to spawn only 4 tasks in parallel?